# Troubles setting SentOn Outlook MailItem property with PropertyAccessor.SetProperty method

Tags: c#, email, datetime, outlook

At the moment I'm working to convert a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` object in a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` one.
Everything seems to be working fine, but I need help to set the `SentOn` MailItem property through the `PropertyAccessor.SetProperty()` method.

I read the sent date info inside the MailMessage header, that returns a string object, then I convert it as DateTime and finally I save this info using the SetProperty() method.

Here is my code:

```
MailMessage mMessage= MailMessageMimeParser.ParseMessage(emlFilePath);
eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
//  here I set 'Subject', 'To', 'CC', 'BCC' etc. properties...
// then try to set the 'SentOn' property
string sentOnString = mMessage.Headers["Date"]; // Wed, 27 May 2015 10:54:39 +0200
DateTime sentOnDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(sentOnString), DateTimeKind.Local); // 5/27/2015 10:54:39 AM
string PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00390040";
eMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME, sentOnDateTime);
eMail.Save(); // here the SentOn property is  5/27/2017 12:54:39 PM
DateTime date = (DateTime)eMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME); // 5/27/2015 10:54:39 AM
...
return eMail; // here the SentOn property is  5/27/2017 12:54:39 PM
```

As my code comments suggest, the right/good date value (5/27/2015 10:54:39 AM) seems to be stored inside the eMail item when I get it with the `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty()` method, but if I try to get it from the `eMail.SentOn` property then I get a wrong date value (5/27/2017 12:54:39 PM).

I've also tried to create the `sentOnDateTime` DateTime with this instruction `DateTime sentOnDateTime = DateTime.Parse("Wed, 27 May 2015 10:54:39");` but the result does not change.

What do you suggest? Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an UTC issue or something. What are the `Kind` of these `DateTime` values? Maybe you need to use `ToLocalTime()` or `ToUniversalTime`?

Comment: When I create the `sentOnDateTime` I specify the `DateTimeKind.Local` value. I've tried also with the `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` value, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if you use `DateTimeKind.Local` - there is nothing in the datetime value that inherently makes it local or UTC. All `SetProperty` sees is an 8 byte float value repressing DateTime in COM.

MAPI stores most `PT_SYSTIME` properties in the UTC time zone, that is what you need to pass to `SetProperty`. `SentOn` property converts UTC to local time when you read it.

As a side note, the bigger problem will be the `Sent` property - OOM will not let you set it, so you will need to create a post item instead of mail item, then change the MessageClass back to `"IPM.Note`" and delete `PR_ICON_INDEX`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), it will let you import MIME files using [RDIOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import` method:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Msg = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Add
  Msg.Sent = true
  Msg.Import "C:\temp\test.eml", 1024
  Msg.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Utc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Unspecified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) value for the second parameter of the [SpecifyKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
  DateTime sentOnDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(sentOnString), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem, the 'SentOn' DateTime property still remains equal to "5/27/2017 12:54:39 PM" also if I use 'Utc' or 'Unspecified' values...